# Configure VS Code keybinding to open a new Powershell script?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

I have the MS Powershell extension installed in VS Code. Other language extensions, e.g. Python, have the ability to assign a keybinding for creating a new file (`python.createNewFile`). I don't see this option in the Powershell extension. There isn't even an option with `Ctrl-Shift-P`.

**EDIT:**
Expanding on the Python example, using a keybinding sequence for `python.createNewFile` will create a new file that already has Python syntax highlighting defined. I don't have to create the file, then save it with a `.py` extension to achieve this. I can get right into the scripting. I'd like to be able to do the same with Powershell.

The only options I have at the moment are to `Ctrl + N`, `Ctrl + S`, and give it a file name with a `.ps1` extension, or `Ctrl + N` and choose "Powershell" from the `Select a Language` list.

Is there another way to do this? A macro or something? There are other Powershell extensions, but as far as I can tell the only way to know the abilities they provide, is to install each one.

Comment: but what name should be given to the new PS1 script? otherwise you could Ctrl+N then Ctrl+S and give it a PS1 extension

Comment: That is an option, yes. But I'd like to eliminate the additional steps in `Ctrl + N`, `Ctrl + S` or `Ctrl + N` then choosing Powershell from the `Select a Language` macro in the new file. Using my Python example, if I define a new keybinding for `Python.createNewFile`, Python is set as the language with its syntax highlighting already defined. I'm hoping to find a way to do this so that I only have to press a key sequence to open a new file with Powershell syntax highlighting already assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place an adapted version of the following in your `keybindings.json` file:

- Open it for editing via the command palette (select menu command `View` > `Command Palette...` or press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd>), command `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`; searching for `keyb json` should be enough to to locate it.

```json
  // Be sure to place this inside the overall enclosing [...]
  // and, if other objects are present, place a "," before/after
  // it to ensure that all objects are ","-separated.
  {
    "key": "shift+f12", // adapt as needed
    "command": "workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile",
    "args": {
      "languageId": "powershell"
    }
  }
```

Thereafter, pressing <kbd>Shift+F12</kbd> will open a new, untitled file and set its language mode to PowerShell, which entails:

- PowerShell-specific syntax highlighting of code in the file.
- The suggested file name when first saving will have extension `.ps1`
- Additionally,  if you have the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) installed (which is advisable for a rich PowerShell authoring and debugging experience):

  - the PIC (PowerShell-Integrated Console) is started in the integrated terminal, which is automatically shown by default.
  - editing is assisted by PowerShell-specific IntelliSense, PowerShell-specific snippets are available, as is debugging of scripts.

---

###### Optional reading: How to discover Visual Studio Code's available API commands:

- As of this writing, the official documentation only describes a *subset* of all built-in commands, in [Built-in commands](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands), which seems to be focused on commands that optionally accept or require *arguments*, i.e. have *parameters*.
- However, as the linked topic notes, a current list of *all* (publicly available) built-in commands can be gleaned from:

  - Interactively, via the GUI, using the view that the `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts` command palette entry (<kbd>Ctrl+K, Ctrl+S</kbd>) opens:

    - You can search for keywords such as `language mode` there.
  - Alternatively, via the virtual JSON-based view of the same information that opens in an editor tab, by choosing `Preferences: Open Default Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` from the command palette.

    - There, the commands are listed by their full names, such as `workbench.action.editor.changeLanguageMode`
  - That said, neither of these views reveal the *arguments* (parameter names) supported by these commands,<sup>[1]</sup> except - in the latter view only - if bound keyboard shortcuts *happen to* use arguments (`"args"` properties).

    - In fact, `workbench.action.editor.changeLanguageMode` - which seems like the logical command to use - is purely a *UI*-based command  and therefore doesn't accept arguments; see next point.
- While the [Built-in commands](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands) topic *does* describe the *specific arguments* a given command supports, that description is sometimes lacking, requiring digging into the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/57ea32b56fa30fe897d3e0f6fa0421117c221146/src/vs/workbench/contrib/files/browser/fileCommands.ts#L666), which is indeed how the specific parameter name (`languageID`) was discovered in the case at hand.

---

<sup>[1] Neither does the [Gist](https://gist.github.com/skfarhat/4e88ef386c93b9dceb98121d9457edbf) you mention in a comment, whose results are based on authoring a dummy extension (and seemingly includes *non-public* commands, prefixed with `_`). The results there are a *snapshot* of the available commands at a given point in time. Fellow users have provided *updated* snapshots over time, but using the methods described above is preferable, as they are guaranteed to be *current* for a given Visual Studio Code installation.</sup>

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. I used your solution to help me track down [a list of commands](https://gist.github.com/skfarhat/4e88ef386c93b9dceb98121d9457edbf) as well.

Comment: Thanks, @theillien - please see my update (bottom section and footnote).